# Write mixed linear model as two level hierarchical model

Tags: multiple-regression

How do I show that this mixed linear model
$$\textbf{Y}=\textbf{X}\beta+\textbf{Zb+e},$$

where
${\textbf{b}\choose \textbf{e}} \sim N\left({\textbf{0} \choose \textbf{0}}, { \textbf{D} 0 \choose 0 \Sigma}\right)$

can be represented by a two-level hierarchical model

$$\textbf{Y|b} \sim N(\textbf{X}\beta+\textbf{Zb},\Sigma),$$
where $\textbf{b} \sim N(\textbf{0},\textbf{D}).$

Comment: Your second equation isn't a two-level hierarchical model, it's just an alternative representation of the first one.

Comment: You probably mean something more like $y_{ij} = \beta_0 + \beta_i x_{ij} + u_j + e_{ij}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you start with
$$
Y\mid b \sim\mathcal N(X\beta + Zb, \Sigma) \\
b \sim \mathcal N(0, D)
$$
then you can use the [tower property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) and [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance), along with the fact that convolutions of Gaussians are Gaussian, to work out the marginal distribution of $Y$. Once you do this, you'll have a Gaussian RV with some mean and covariance. Then compare that to the marginal distribution of $X\beta + Zb + e$ and you should have your answer.